# Zipping files that has been created during a certain date

Tags: bash, zip, gzip

I'm trying to zip a lot of files in a directory, but I need to zip them by year.
I am using the following command to find the files:

```
find  /destination_path/ -newermt 20160101 -not -newermt 20170101
```

What can I pipe to using `|` in order to zip these files?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Try piping to `xargs` and then `zip`

```
find  /destination_path/ -newermt 20160101 -not -newermt 20170101 | xargs -n1 zip 20170101.zip
```

Comment: No problem. Please accept my answer if it helped you. Thanks. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work